# Loading dynamic content to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is the script which i have old which just throws the content in the `response.php`

index.php

```
<input type="button" id="fire" value="Show Items">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fire").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "response.php",
             data: { 
            'test': 'test', 
        },
            success : function(data)
            {

            $("#result").html(data);
            }
        },"json");
    });
    </script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

response.php

```
<?php
echo '

    <input type="text" id="startingloc">
    <input type="text" id="endingloc">';
?>
```

I try to make the google autosuggest which will come by this code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#startingloc").on("input",function() {

        //alert("Change detected!");
        console.log("Changed");

    });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("startingloc"));
                  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("endingloc"));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
            });
        });

    </script>
    <input type="text" id="startingloc">
    <input type="text" id="endingloc">
```

I am getting

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

When i try to add the javascript in the home page i am not getting autosuggest overt there.

How can i fix this ?

**Here is the latest code i have**

index.php

```
<input type="button" id="fire" value="Show Items">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fire").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "response.php",
             data: { 
            'test': 'test', 
        },
            success : function(data)
            {

            $("#result").html(data);
            }
        },"json");
    });
    </script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

response.php

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("startingloc"));
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("endingloc"));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="startingloc">
    <input type="text" id="endingloc">';
?>
```

Comment: The error message is complaining about using `document.write()`, but I don't see that anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: i don't have document.write() and I have updated the latest code..

Comment: what if you remove google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {} . But keep the code which is inside the function

Comment: Why do you need to load it dynamically anyway?

Comment: I am loading it dynamically bcoz if i add it to the parent page, the autosuggest is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
```

[ And it's end `});`  ]

in your `response.php`

And don't try to load the `.js` from your ajax page and always load it from the parent page.

So your code will be

`response.php`

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("startingloc"));
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("endingloc"));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
            });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="startingloc">
    <input type="text" id="endingloc">';
?>
```

And your `index.php` will remain the same

Comment: Thanks it worked a mass ! and i realized `document.ready` = `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {`